# Deduce that relation must hold for all unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

If we have the vector $$V = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle) = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

where $|00\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and  $|11\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. It can quickly be shown that

$$(A \otimes I) |V\rangle = (I \otimes A^{T}) |V\rangle$$

holds for any arbitrary 2x2 matrix A, if $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$, and $I$ is the 2x2 identity matrix.

The resulting vector is just $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}$

my question is then: How can i use only this knowledge from the part above, to deduce that the following must be true for all unitary matrices U? $V$ is the very same vector as defined initially:

$$(U \otimes \bar{U})|V\rangle = |V\rangle$$

$\bar{U}$ denotes the complex conjugated. I have been stuck on this for a while now, even though it might be rather obvious to some. What information from the first part of my question is enough to deduce that the above equation must be true for all unitary matrices U?

I have tried to write out ($(U \otimes \bar{U})$), but this does not get me any closer:

$$\begin{pmatrix}aa^{*} & ab^{*} & ba^{*} & bb^{*} \\ ac^{*} & ad^{*} & bc^{*} & bd^{*} \\ ca^{*} & cb^{*} & da^{*} & db^{*} \\ cc^{*} & cd^{*} & dc^{*} & dd^{*}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}aa^{*}+bb^{*}\\ac^{*}+bd^{*}\\ca^{*}+db^{*}\\cc^{*}+dd^{*}\end{pmatrix}$$

I can see that i get the terms $aa^{*}$ and $dd^{*}$, which is fine - but i have no arguments as to why all the other terms should vanish. I think this might be the wrong approach, and there is something much simpler i am missing. I feel i am going around in circles, coming close to an understanding, but still far from. Any hints and/or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get this equation from? It doesn't seem to be true for general unitary matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got this from an exercise in quantum information theory. I assume it is implied that the unitary matrices need to be 2x2 otherwise the dimensions wont fit. I tried using the three Pauli matrices which are unitary and it gave the expected result. Do you have an example of a unitary that does not fit this?

Comment: If $$U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}i & -1 \\ 1 & -i\end{pmatrix}$$ will give you $$(U\otimes U^*)|V\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\  -i \\ -i \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ assuming you have written $(U\otimes U^*)|V\rangle$ correctly in your question.

Comment: I think he means by $U^*$ the conjugate transpose, not only the conjugate.

Comment: @jobe Yes, that is clear in how he calculated $(U\otimes U^*)|V\rangle$. I am simply plugging in the entries of my example $U$ into his calculated $(U\otimes U^*)|V\rangle$

Comment: You are right @bames, the equality is not true for all unitary matrices.

Comment: I just calculated your example, and got the same answer as you. Then i may have screwed up by rewriting the initial state. Not that the rewriting is wrong, but it might be important to this deduction. The vector V originally looks like this $V = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ where $|00\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and  $|11\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ . I have edited my original question to include this information.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge The result is pretty much the same for the $U$ I gave. Is this exactly what the exercise tells you to prove? Are you sure there are no additional constraints on $U$?

Comment: Yes that is all the information i have unfortunately. My ket state (vector V) is called a Bell state, just as an extra information. The only assumption i made was that in the exercise $U^{*}$ is written $\bar{U}$ but from the context it can not be anything but the complex conjugate? Even though it is not typical to use a bar, it is however seen.

I can see that if the bar only denotes the transpose instead of the complex conjugate i get the correct answer with your unitary matrix. I almost hope that this isn't the solution. That would almost be to frustrating.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge If $U^*$ is the complex conjugate and not the conjugate transpose, then you have calculated $U\otimes U^*$ incorrectly.

Comment: As i wrote in my last edit to my last comment, i have realised that if $U^{*}$ just denotes the complex conjugate (it is written $\bar{U}$ in my exercise) then everything works fine. I feel so stupid. I guess an extra lesson i have learned is to make sure i write an absolute identical copy of my equations next time i pose a question. But now the original question remains. How do i deduce that this relation holds for any unitary matrix?

Comment: @CuriousGeorge Ok, I will do so in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a general unitary matrix $U = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\-e^{i\phi}\bar b & e^{i\phi}\bar a\end{pmatrix}$. Then:
\begin{align}
(U\otimes\bar U)(|00\rangle+|11\rangle) &= U\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes\bar U\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} + U\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\otimes \bar U\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix}a \\ -e^{i\phi}\bar b\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}\bar a \\ -e^{-i\phi}b\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}b \\ e^{i\phi}\bar a\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}\bar b \\ e^{-i\phi}a\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}a\bar a & -e^{-i\phi}ab\\-e^{i\phi}\bar b\bar a & \bar b b\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}b\bar b & e^{-i\phi}ab\\e^{i\phi}\bar b \bar a & \bar a a\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \\
& = |00\rangle + |11\rangle
\end{align}

---

If you want to do it using your vector $\begin{pmatrix}a\bar a+b\bar b\\a\bar c+b\bar d\\c\bar a+d\bar b\\c\bar c+d\bar d\end{pmatrix}$ in the edited version of your question, note that a unitary matrix $U = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}$ must satisfy:

$$UU^* = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\bar a & \bar c \\\bar b & \bar d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a\bar a + b \bar b & a\bar c + b \bar d \\\bar a c + d\bar b & c\bar c + d \bar d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
So your vector must be $$(U\otimes \bar U)|V\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

---

Using the first part of your question (which I forgot about), you get
\begin{align}(U\otimes\bar U)|V\rangle &= (U\otimes I)(I\otimes \bar U)|V\rangle \\ &= (U\otimes I)(U^*\otimes I)|V\rangle \\ &= (UU^*\otimes I)|V\rangle \\ &= (I\otimes I)|V\rangle  \\ &= |V\rangle\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. I would rather do it with the vector notation in the last part of your answer. This seems more intuitive to me, because the 'general form' of a unitary already assumes that U is unitary. I can not see why the the terms $a\bar{c}+b\bar{d}$ and $c\bar{a}+d\bar{b}$ vanish? I assume that what you meant by the last part of your answer is that since my final dimensions are 4x4 and not 2x2 i should end up getting a 4x4 identity along my original vector?

Comment: @CuriousGeorge Since $UU^* = I$ (where $U^*$ is the conjugate transpose, not the conjugate of $U$) for any unitary matrix, you can see that the off-diagonal entries of $UU^*$ must be zero. This is a requirement for all unitary matrices. These off-diagonal entries are exactly $a\bar c + b\bar d$ and $\bar a c + d \bar b$. As a side note, the general form of a unitary matrix in the first part of my answer is the general form because _all_ unitary matrices may be written in this form.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge What do you mean by the last question in your comment? Do you mean that you think $U\otimes \bar U$ is the $4\times 4$ identity?

Comment: No i realise that $U \otimes \bar{U}$ is definitely not the 4x4 identity. By last equation i mean where you write "So your vector must be". I see what you mean now by the fact that the cross-terms must equal zero for the equation $UU^{*}=I$ to hold. I am satisfied with this solution, but i must admit that it doesn't seem like i needed to use anything from the first part as my exercise states. Maybe there is a neat trick with showing some properties of matrix A from the beginning of my question needs to be unitary...

Comment: @CuriousGeorge You could decompose $(U\otimes \bar U)|V\rangle$ into \begin{align}(U\otimes\bar U)|V\rangle &= (U\otimes I)(I\otimes \bar U)|V\rangle \\ &= (U\otimes I)(U^*\otimes I)|V\rangle \\ &= (UU^*\otimes I)|V\rangle \\ &= (I\otimes I)|V\rangle  \\ &= |V\rangle\end{align} I forgot about that first part of your question, to be honest. Seems much neater!

Comment: That is exactly the kind of thing i had i mind! I searched for a relation like that, without any luck. Does this decomposition have a specific name or is there anywhere i can read more about it? Thank you again for your help and your patience.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge The initial decomposition of $U\otimes \bar U$ into $(U\otimes I)(I\otimes \bar U)$ is a basic property of tensor products. There are a few more here: https://csustan.csustan.edu/~tom/MISC/qc-article/node3.html that might be useful in the future. The rest is just taking advantage of your ket $|V\rangle$'s behavior from the first part of your question! :)

Comment: @CuriousGeorge Here, I just found the Wikipedia page with these properties. Take a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Properties

Comment: Beautiful and simple solution, also very useful properties. Thanks once again.